# ios: Wrong image loading from php script

Tags: php, ios, image, uiimage

In my app, I use a php script that redirects to an image. After I changed the picture on the server, the app on only one device continued to load the older picture. I don't save the picture locally anywhere, and I load the picture from the server every time. The right picture was loading correctly on other devices and after I deleted and re-built the app on my current device. What could have caused the problem?

my php code looks like this:

> $userid = $_POST['userid'];

```
$query = "SELECT image FROM Users WHERE userid='$userid'";

$results = mysql_query($query);

$user = mysql_fetch_array($results);

$image = $user['image'];

header("Location:../profile_images/".$image);
```

Comment: can you post the code of `I use a php script that redirects to an image`

Comment: I think it's caching problem. Do you clean cache on your browser?

Comment: it might be a cache problem, but it's on my application. I am not using a uiwebview or a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to do a **`force reload`** of the image. So every time the image is requested a new one will appear. Change your header like this.

```
header("Location:../profile_images/".$image."?".rand(1,3000));
```

Comment: so this will prevent any cached images from being received by the application?